# Excel VBA Error 400 when sub is ran, but no error in debug step through?

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory, shapes

This is more of a thought question, I have a sub that draws pictures and saves them as a shape object in an excel workbook. It usually handles less than 15 or so shapes well, but when I start to get above 15 it throws error 400, presumably out of memory? Other times I have had over 300 work fine.

I have a list of 35 shapes I needed to draw, I tried it three times each time it crashed so I stepped through the code line by line. What baffled me was that stepping through allowed the program to draw every shape and not crash out like it had the past three times. I'm at a loss why this works in debug mode but not in 'normal' run mode.

```
Declare Function CDKSmilesImageToClipboard Lib "cdkInterfaceDll.dll" Alias "_smilesToClipboardCdkInterfaceDll@12" (ByVal smiles As String, ByVal width As Long, ByVal height As Long) As Long

Dim i As Integer, LastRow As Long, SMILES As String, temp As Long

For i = 6 To LastRow
    SMILES = Sheets("Table").Cells(i, 7).Value2
    temp = CDKSmilesImageToClipboard(SMILES, 150, 115)
    Sheets("Table").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Table").Cells(i, 7)
    Sheets("Table").Shapes(Sheets("Table").Shapes.Count).Name = "Structure " & i
    Sheets("Table").Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "Structure " & i
Next i
```

I expect the error that is occurring at run-time should also occur when I step through the code. But its not. The 400 error is as equivocal as can be, so I'm not even sure its an OOM error. So I'm turning to the Stack for guidance. Has anyone ever seen this before? Is there anything I can add to my code to slow down or walk through the shape drawing?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you add `DoEvents` after `temp = CDKSmilesImageToClipboard(SMILES, 150, 115)` and after `Sheets("Table").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Table").Cells(i, 7)`?

Comment: Thank you Siddharth, it does make the 35 list work! But not when I add the list size to 500. n

Comment: Then you need to share what `CDKSmilesImageToClipboard(SMILES, 150, 115)` does. The thing is, we need to give excel enough time to process things. We can do that by using `DoEvents` at necessary places...

Comment: Thanks again, I'll dig for that function but it's from an external library... Thanks!

Comment: What's so perplexing about this for me is that it throws the error at different points each time. How can it make it to shape 100 one iteration, 12 the next iteration, 47 the next iteration when everything is exactly the same?

Comment: The code may be the same but there is lot of things happening in the background. I need to see specifically how is the image being stored in the clipboard. Any chance I can see the code for `CDKSmilesImageToClipboard`

Comment: Are you shelling out to CDK to produce your images?  That's likely the issue here - timing can be a problem when you leave the immediate VBA environment.  Also if you're willing to share that Sub I'd be interested to see how you do that...

Comment: Hi Tim, yes I am using the CDK API to draw the images. I've been trying to find where the code is for the sub, it links to a DLL I installed on my computer called cdkInterfaceDll.dll but I cant find the function on github. I have updated the way I call the function in my code above. Hope this helps, sorry I cannot provide the explicit code of the CDK sub. If I find it I will provide it.

Comment: Do you have the GitHub link?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/cdk/cdk I'm very unfamiliar with this depth of code, thank you for helping. Happy to help you any way I can.

Comment: Thanks I will find some time for that - a bit more involved though...

Comment: Very much appreciated Tim, thank you!

Comment: So I did some more digging. I 'think' this is the Java code for the relevant ImageToClipboard: https://github.com/CDK-R/cdkr/blob/master/rcdkjar/src/org/guha/rcdk/view/MoleculeImageToClipboard.java    Im trying to use VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") and run with wait on return option active. The issue I run into is that I dont know where the code really is, and its not a *.exe (I'm very unfamiliar with this code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a, less than 100% ideal, workaround for the problem I was having. It's posted below for completeness and for reference in the future.

Adding the error handling structure below, I was able to prevent the sub from crashing or skipping error draws (would draw a blank pic when I used On Error Resume Next).

```
Declare Function CDKSmilesImageToClipboard Lib "cdkInterfaceDll.dll" Alias "_smilesToClipboardCdkInterfaceDll@12" (ByVal smiles As String, ByVal width As Long, ByVal height As Long) As Long

Dim i As Integer, LastRow As Long, SMILES As String, temp As Long

For i = 6 To LastRow
ReDo:
    On Error GoTo ErrCatch
    SMILES = Sheets("Table").Cells(i, 7).Value2
    temp = CDKSmilesImageToClipboard(SMILES, 150, 115)
ErrCatch:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo -1   'Resets the Err Catcher
        On Error GoTo ErrCatch   'Recalibrates the Err Catcher
        GoTo ReDo    'Redoes the image draw/paste
    End If
    Sheets("Table").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Table").Cells(i, 7)
    DoEvents
    Sheets("Table").Shapes(Sheets("Table").Shapes.Count).Name = "Structure " & i
    Sheets("Table").Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "Structure " & i
Next i
```

Adding the error handling prevents the 400 errors by redoing the draw/paste loop. I wish I could directly prevent the error from occurring in the first place, but this results in an acceptable outcome 100% of the time :) Thanks guys for your help!